# Generate entities from tables in Glassfish 3.1 for Eclipse 3.7

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

I am trying to go through [this tutorial](http://programming.manessinger.com/tutorials/an-eclipse-glassfish-java-ee-6-tutorial/) to learn more on Glassfish.  I am at [the stage](http://programming.manessinger.com/tutorials/an-eclipse-glassfish-java-ee-6-tutorial/#heading_toc_j_25) of creating Java entities from DB tables and the tutorial instructs to " In the context menu of the EJB project (and only there) you’ll find **JPA Tools / Generate Entities from Tables**".  However, I can't find that option in the EJB project menu.  I suppose the tutorial is a bit stale and based off of a previous version of GF for Eclipse.  Can anybody tell what the updated functionality of this is, i.e. how to generate Java entity classes from DB so I can carry on with my tutorial?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, i have noticed this question right now, i'll answer it although think it's too late.
JPA tools generally are not included in EJP Projects so you have to include them manually: go in **Properties** of your EJB, select between the options **Project Facets** and next check JPA. After it, you'll find JPA tools in EJP just  pressing right click on your EJP project. 
Hope it helped to someone.